# how to compute html page first, then refresh

Tags: html

I have a web-page that uses `http-equiv="Refresh" content="30"` to rewrite itself every so often.  The process of deciding what to write is computationally intensive so that when it comes time to rewrite, the text on the page appears in chunks, with delays in between.  The whole process takes several seconds.

This is ugly.  It would be much better, to compute the whole page first, every 30 seconds, and when that is done, replace the old page with the new one.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move beyond the "dumb" `meta` refresh. You could, say, implement [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics), via JavaScript. Or use ajax to only refresh the parts of the page which are stale.